# gnu C, value to string, preprocessor magic

Tags: c, gnu, preprocessor

Friend,
there are a lots of enum values

```
enum{
ABC = 123,
XYZ = 456,
FOO = 4321,
BAR = 98743,
...
}
```

when I got the value, I want print the enum's NAME. we could create a string , value pair array. but have to repeat literally the enum body. if enum changed, then array has to be changed accordingly.
I remember preprocess could do magic, create enum list, also generate string, value array with one body.

hope masters here could give me a guide.

thanks
Xian

Answer (score 2):

In my_enum.inc:

```c
MY_ENUM_ITEM(ABC, 123)
MY_ENUM_ITEM(XYZ, 456)
MY_ENUM_ITEM(FOO, 4321)
MY_ENUM_ITEM(BAR, 98743)
```

Then to define the enum itself use something like:

```c
enum my_enum {
#define MY_ENUM_ITEM(_n, _v) _n = _v,
#include "my_enum.inc"
#undef MY_ENUM_ITEM
};
```

and to convert from a value to a string:

```c
const char *my_enum_to_string(enum my_enum e) {
    switch (e) {
#define MY_ENUM_ITEM(_n, _v) case _v: return #_n;
#include "my_enum.inc"
#undef MY_ENUM_ITEM
    default: return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, you are genius! worked great. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a hashmap, instead of using the C preprocessor?

Comment: hashmap is kind of overkill.  yes, it is an options.